# How to make scrolling smoothly and pinch to zoom in both vertical and horizontal direction

Tags: android, scrollview, zooming, pinchzoom

I have implemented a pinch to zoom for my textview. It works fine without scroll. But I want both zoom and scroll as I have long content. When I put scroll, the zoom and scroll works but not smoothly plus I have to move my fingers only in horizontal directions. If I move the fingers upside down then it scrolls.

ZoomView.java

```
public class ZoomView extends TextView {
private static final String TAG = "ZoomTextView";
private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;

private float mScaleFactor = 1.f;
private float defaultSize;

private float zoomLimit = 3.0f;


public ZoomView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    initialize();
}

public ZoomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initialize();
}

public ZoomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    initialize();
}

private void initialize() {
    defaultSize = getTextSize();
    mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(getContext(), new ScaleListener());

}

public void setZoomLimit(float zoomLimit) {
    this.zoomLimit = zoomLimit;
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(@NonNull MotionEvent ev) {
    super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
    return true;
}

private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
        mScaleFactor = Math.max(1.0f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, zoomLimit));
        setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, defaultSize * mScaleFactor);
        Log.e(TAG, String.valueOf(mScaleFactor));
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

Vithale.java

```
public class vithale extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_vithale);
}
}
```

activity_vithale.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/sc">
<com.example.acer.myapplication.ZoomView
    android:id="@+id/iop"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/twentyfive"/>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You can use Sensey library to achieve your goal- https://github.com/nisrulz/sensey

Comment: @MohitCharadva could you please help in how to implement this in my project?

Answer (score 0):

By just adding this lines to vithale.java fixed the zoom and scroll problem but only thing is that scrolling is not smooth

ZoomView iop = (ZoomView) findViewById(R.id.iop);
        iop.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());